# Snowflake cannot use schema

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I created new user, and new role. I assigned to the user that role.
These are the role privileges:

```
GRANT OWNERSHIP ON SCHEMA <DB name>.<schema name> TO ROLE <role name>;
GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE <DB name> TO ROLE <role name>;
```

But I still failing on

```
USE SCHEMA <schema name>;

002043 (02000): SQL compilation error:
Object does not exist, or operation cannot be performed.
```

**Edit 1:**
With new schema it does work, it stops working if the schema was created by another user with another role and then I grant the ownership of that schema to the newly create role

**Edit 2:**
Also when I ran `show SCHEMAS;` the schema I granted ownership to, is not displayed, only the schemas that the user have created

Comment: Is that role also granted to your user id, and are you actively using that role?  Also, did you create the schema with / without quotes?

Comment: Are you sure it is issued in context of <db_name>?  `USE <DB name>.<schema name>`?

Answer (score 0):

This all worked without problem for me:

```sql
use role accountadmin;
create role delete_stacko;
grant role delete_stacko to role sysadmin;

create schema temp.delete_schema;
grant ownership on schema temp.delete_schema to role delete_stacko;
grant usage on database temp to role delete_stacko;

use role delete_stacko;
use schema temp.delete_schema;
```

I created a new role, a new schema, and when switching to that role I had all permissions needed to use that schema. Make sure to check that the schema is in the database you are trying to work with - or use prefixes to be completely sure.

Comment: It also works for me when I use a user with ACCOUNTADMIN role even if I switch to the new role. The problem is with new USER

Comment: Did you grant the role to the user? `grant role delete_stacko to user the_new_user;`. Remember the user also needs to use that role with `use role delete_stacko`. I just created a new user to try this, and everything worked well.

Comment: I did grant the user that role. I edited my question with more findings, looks like it doesn't work if I pass the ownership of the schema. (create schema with role1 and then try to use it with role2 even that I did change ownership so that role2 should be the owner)

Comment: Maybe `GRANT OWNERSHIP` is not enough, you also need to `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES` https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-ownership.html#examples